# Tracking differences between two SQL tables (added, removed, changed)

Tags: sql, join, difference

Suppose I have the following table `A`:

```
create table A (
    code-id integer primary key,
    code-name-1 varchar(200) not null,
    code-name-2 varchar(200) not null,
    foreign key (code-id) references another-table(code-id)
);
```

And one more table, `B`:

```
create table B (
    code-id integer primary key,
    code-name-1 varchar(200) not null,
    code-name-2 varchar(200) not null,
    foreign key (code-id) references another-table(code-id)
);
```

Both tables, `A` and `B` hold unique `code-id` references into `another-table` which is not relevant to the question.

Is it possible to write a single query that can identify in one fell swoop:

- Which `code-id`s are in `A` but not in `B`.
- Which `code-id`s are in `B` but not in `A`.
- Which `code-id`s are the same in `A` and `B`, but their `code-name-1` or `code-name-2` values are different (either of them).

I believe that this could be solved by one `left join` clause, with its results concatenated to a `right join` clause, with its results concatenated to a third inner `join` clause, enhanced with two string comparison predicates for the `on` clause.

- Am I on the right track?
- Can I generate an additional column specifying the result of the operation? E.g. column `RESULT` with values `ADDED`, `REMOVED`, `CHANGED`?
- Is there a more clever way to specify this query, rather than having to concatenate three `join` clauses?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use an Except, similar to a Union but it gives you the data that is in one and not in the other. Use that for the first 2. Then you can use an Intersect which will give you the rows that are same in both tables. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191523(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use EXCEPT operand and one join like this

```
Select code-id, 'added' result from a
Except
Select code-id, 'added' result from b
Union all
Select code-id, 'removed' result from b
Except
Select code-id, 'removed' result from a
Union all
Select code-id, 'changed' result 
from a join b on a.code-id = b.code-id 
Where a.code-name-1 != b.code-name-1 or a.code-name-2 != b.code-name-2
```

Comment: I'm working on Oracle, so I resorted to using left outer joins instead. However, this idea worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In A but not in B

```
Select code-id from A
Except
Select code-id from B
```

In B but not in A

```
Select code-id from B
Except
Select code-id from A
```

In Both A and B

```
Select code-id from A
Intersect
Select code-id from B
```

As a single query, you should be able to UNION them Together

```
Select code-id from A
    Except
    Select code-id from B
UNION
Select code-id from B
    Except
    Select code-id from A
UNION
Select code-id from A
    Intersect
    Select code-id from B
```